Azure Unity Catalogue
I have recently started learning Azure Databricks, While setting up unity catalogue I had confusion, Why we need the third party connector (Azure Databricks Connector) while creating unity catalogue if the aim is to be able to access the storage account, won't service principal work ? I'm confused why there is a need for the connector.

The Azure Databricks access connector is actually a type of service principal. It only makes connecting easier, since you don't need to specify client_id, secret etc. in a notebook, you can use the access connector name in the UI or code, and Databricks will use it to connect to the storage account.

Unity catalog is decoupled from storage. It has the metadata of the underlying data and a lot of other metadata, and it is a separate  database somewhere else. Your Service Principal might have access to Azure storage but not to Unity Catalog, a different Azure resource.
